# Show TextView for an empty ListView inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a tabbed layout and an activity using tabs as views. It has three tabs as `ListViews`. If either of the lists is empty I want to show a simple `TextView` instead. I've gone through many posts but all of them talk about a single `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout`. I'm not sure if it is not working because of multiple `ListViews` or `FrameLayout`. Can we not set **visibility = GONE** inside a `FrameLayout`? Because even then the `TextView` is always shown along with the `ListView`. Can anyone suggest what can be done in this scenario?

I also tried including `TextView` in another xml file. But I'm not sure how to add that `TextView` to my `FrameLayout`.

This is what I'm doing for m all three `ListViews`

```
TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blank);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);

mListView_top10 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Top_10);
if(TopWR.size()!=0) {
      mListView_top10.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row,TopWR));
} else {
  frameLayout.addView(empty);
}
```

FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background="@drawable/innerdashboard_bg"
        android:layout_weight="1">


            <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/Top_10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:text="this is a tab" />


        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/Billable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:text="this is another tab" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Product"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="this is a third tab" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

TextView

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/blank"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="No records Avaible"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried using `setEmptyView`, for all three `ListViews` using separate empty views, doesn't work!

```
TextView empty1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blank1);
mListView_top10 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Top_10);
mListView_top10.setEmptyView(empty1);
mListView_top10.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row,TopWR));
```

xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/innerdashboard_bg"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/Top_10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/Top_10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:text="this is a tab" />

            <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/blank1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="No records Avaible"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/Billable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/Billable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:text="this is another tab" />

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/blank2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="No records Avaible"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/Product"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Product"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="this is a third tab" />

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/blank3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="No records Avaible"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call [`setEmptyView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) on your `ListView`, passing in the `TextView` as argument.

```
TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blank);
mListView_top10.setEmptyView(empty);
```

The `ListView` should automatically take care of toggling the visibility of the 'empty' view.

Tip: since the argument is a generic `View`, you can pass in any subclass of `View`, or more complex view hierarchy.

On a side note: you will probably have to give each `ListView` its own `TextView` instance as empty view to avoid clashing scenarios; e.g. when one list does have content, while another doesn't.

Comment: I tried that. But it doesn't work! I guess that is because my activity doesn't extend `ListActivity`. `setEmptyView` only works under `ListActivity` right?

Comment: I've edited my code. Please have a look again. I keep getting this `Exception[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4063add0`

Answer (score 1):

I would insist you to use `ViewStub` here with a `ListView` inside a FrameLayout. When your ListView has data you can use `VIEW.GONE` to `ViewStub` and if your ListView is no data then use `VIEW.VISIBLE` for the ViewStub. You can download example from [`github`](https://github.com/lalit3686/ListViewEmpty) and get it working.

Comment: Do I have to create another class like `CheeseAdapter` and make it extend to `BaseAdapter`? I mean is that why it wasn't working?

Comment: No, as you are using inbuilt ArrayAdapter you can just create a method that check the size of the collection and perform accordingly.

Comment: I tried that. it didn't work! I mean the `TextView` was visible even when a list wasn't empty. But I didn't use `ViewStub` then. It was a simple `TextView`. Was that what was missing then?

Comment: I have multiple `ListViews` inside a `FrameLayout`. Do I need to have multiple `ViewStub` as well?

Comment: Check this one for ArrayAdapter and read the blog to get beter idea ..http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=422

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding an empty item when the list is empty.  The following example is based on your pre-EDIT code:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);

mListView_top10 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Top_10);
if (TopWR.size() == 0) {
  // add a single item to the array, in order to indicate the list is empty
  TopWR.add("The List Is Empty");
}
mListView_top10.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row,TopWR));
```

If you want to get fancier with how the empty list is displayed you can replace ArrayAdapter with a custom adapter.  You can also use a different adapter when the list is empty.

Comment: This is what I've currently settle for. But displaying the empty list as a list item with modified text isn't a good approach. It looks like a list item after all. I wanted to show a `TextView` instead in the middle of the layout with it's own font than showing up a text in the left corner of the page as if it were a genuine list item. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Visibility on each of the ListViews in your java code?

```
TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blank);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);


mListView_top10 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Top_10);
      if(TopWR.size()!=0) {
          mListView_top10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          mListView_top10.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listview_row,TopWR));


      }
      else {
          mListView_top10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          frameLayout.addView(empty);

      }
```

TextView

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="No records Avaible"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: Yeah! I tried this too. The problem is with the visibility of `TextView` It shows up even when list isn't empty

Comment: Doesn't work! I think addView is causing a problem. I get an Exception.

Comment: This: `Exception[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4063add0`